# Meaning of 爱惜花草树木

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, idioms

I'm trying to get the meaning of the following expression: **爱惜花草树木**. A Chinese friend told me that it's something like "*It's so corny*", but I'm having a hard time finding an explanation online. I've found a few Chinese websites but the explanation Chinese is way too hard for me :-/

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with the meaning. It is actually overused on the signs so your friend would say that.

Comment: I believe if you live in China you can see it everywhere wherever there is a ground with grass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple terms it means to treasure nature. It literally means "love and treasure flowers, grass, trees".

You'd generally find it on park signs so that it's a catch all for people not to trample on grass, to not pick flowers, wreck trees, that sort of thing.